# Pythonic way to flatten nested dictionarys

Tags: python, hash-map

Here's my attempt to write a function that flattens a nested dictionary structure in Python 3.6

This came about because I had a nested dictionary structure of data I wanted to visualize in the library `Bokeh`.

I didn't like other examples that require a recursive function call. (I find it difficult to reason about, and I believe python has a relative small recursion limit)

Tell me about the styling, ease of (or lack of) understanding and what you would do.

Here's my code:

```
def flatten_dict(dictionary, delimiter='.'):
    """
    Function to flatten a nested dictionary structure
    :param dictionary: A python dict()
    :param delimiter:  The desired delimiter between 'keys'
    :return: dict()
    """

    #
    # Assign the actual dictionary to the one that will be manipulated
    #
    dictionary_ = dictionary

    def unpack(parent_key, parent_value):
        """
        A function to unpack one level of nesting in a python dictionary
        :param parent_key: The key in the parent dictionary being flattened
        :param parent_value: The value of the parent key, value pair
        :return: list(tuple(,))
        """

        #
        # If the parent_value is a dict, unpack it
        #
        if isinstance(parent_value, dict):
            return [
                (parent_key + delimiter + key, value)
                for key, value
                in parent_value.items()
            ]
        #
        # If the If the parent_value is a not dict leave it be
        #
        else:
            return [
                (parent_key, parent_value)
            ]

    #
    # Keep unpacking the dictionary until all value's are not dictionary's
    #
    while True:
        #
        # Loop over the dictionary, unpacking one level. Then reduce the dimension one level
        #
        dictionary_ = dict(
            ii
            for i
            in [unpack(key, value) for key, value in dictionary_.items()]
            for ii
            in i
        )
        #
        # Break when there is no more unpacking to do
        #
        if all([
            not isinstance(value, dict)
            for value
            in dictionary_.values()
        ]):
            break

    return dictionary_
```

Comment: Hi, your code works like a charm. Consider making a lib/package of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks good, but I noticed a few PEP8 things that could be improved:

[PEP8 for comments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments)

Why are you adding extra empty comment lines around your comments?

```
#
# Loop over the dictionary, unpacking one level. Then reduce the dimension one level
#
```

This could just be:

```
# Loop over the dictionary, unpacking one level. Then reduce the dimension one level
```

There's no need to add additional fluff to your comments.

Also, if your comment has multiple sentences in it, it looks nicer to end with a full stop:

```
# Loop over the dictionary, unpacking one level. Then reduce the dimension one level.
```

[PEP257 for docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257)

Docstrings should be written like a command, not an explanation.

Also, the first line of your docstring should be on the same line as the starting three quotes, but the ending three quotes should be on a new line.

This:

```
"""
Function to flatten a nested dictionary structure
:param dictionary: A python dict()
:param delimiter:  The desired delimiter between 'keys'
:return: dict()
"""
```

could be this:

```
"""Flatten a nested dictionary structure.

Arguments:
dictionary -- dict to flatten
delimiter -- desired delimiter between keys

Return a flattened dict.
"""
```

Comment: Cheers for the review. To answer, I saw it done in someone else's module and thought i'd try it out.  I did not know that about doc strings. I will make  sure to structure them like a command in the future! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 10):

> ```
>     dictionary_ = dict(
>         ii
>         for i
>         in [unpack(key, value) for key, value in dictionary_.items()]
>         for ii
>         in i
>     )
> ```

This is probably the worst part in the code, yet this is pretty much the whole code. Variable names are terrible and the intent is a bit hidden. I understand that `unpack` returns lists so your list-comprehension generates a list of lists. So this expression is flattening a list of list of tuples and turning it into a dictionary.

For starter, flattening iterables of iterables can be achieved more easily using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) so you just need `dictionary_ = dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable([unpack(key, value) for key, value in dictionary_.items()]))` and get rid of the awful variable names.

Second, and this also apply to the `all()` call, you can use simpler generator expression instead of full list-comprehension to play it nicer with the memory. This only means removing the square brackets around the expression:

```
dictionary_ = dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        unpack(key, value) for key, value in dictionary_.items()
))
```

Lastly, but this is highly debatable, I would use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) instead of the whole expression:

```
dictionary_ = dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.starmap(unpack, dictionary_.items()))
```

---

I would also change `unpack` to fit more nicely with these changes: make it a generator instead of building lists (that you are going to discard right away). And just to propose an alternative way, I’ll go with an [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach:

```
def unpack(parent_key, parent_value):
    """A function to unpack one level of nesting in a dictionary"""

    try:
        items = parent_value.items()
    except AttributeError:
        # parent_value was not a dict, no need to flatten
        yield (parent_key, parent_value)
    else:
        for key, value in items:
            yield (parent_key + delimiter + key, value)
```

---

You may also find this function to choke on dictionaries whose keys are not strings. This is due to the `parent_key + delimiter + key` part that will fail to "concatenate" numbers and strings for instance. Or any custom object…

There are two solutions to this problem depending on the intended use-case:

1. use `str.format` to convert each key to a string;
2. use a tuple as the flattened key instead of a string.

I prefer the second solution as a key of `'3.14'` can ambiguously be comming from the key `'3'` and `'14'` or `'3.14'` in the first solution. Whole code would be:

```
from itertools import chain, starmap


def flatten_dict(dictionary):
    """Flatten a nested dictionary structure"""

    def unpack(parent_key, parent_value):
        """Unpack one level of nesting in a dictionary"""
        try:
            items = parent_value.items()
        except AttributeError:
            # parent_value was not a dict, no need to flatten
            yield (parent_key, parent_value)
        else:
            for key, value in items:
                yield (parent_key + (key,), value)

    # Put each key into a tuple to initiate building a tuple of subkeys
    dictionary = {(key,): value for key, value in dictionary.items()}

    while True:
        # Keep unpacking the dictionary until all value's are not dictionary's
        dictionary = dict(chain.from_iterable(starmap(unpack, dictionary.items()))
        if not any(isinstance(value, dict) for value in dictionary.values()):
            break

    return dictionary
```

Comment: Must admit 'terrible variable names' was tough to stomach... haha. Is there a standard variable to name to indicate a non-meaningful value? Appreciate the explanation of the itertool functions. I find once i see a working example of its use. I start think how else i could use it. Ta!

Comment: @JamesSchinner by convention, `_` is used when there is a need for a variable name somewhere in the code but that variable is never used anywhere else. This is what non-meaningful is to me. Otherwise you need a name that help convey the intent. Some short names are universally understood, like `i`, `j`, `k` for (loop) counters/indices or `x`, `y`, `z` as point coordinates. But in general you want more descriptive names. `unpacked` and `flattened` can be replacement for `ii` and `i` but I fail to find really good names. Naming is hard.

Comment: `dictionary = dict(chain.from_iterable(starmap(unpack, dictionary.items()))` is missing a right paren at the end.